# Randomize unit-tests using cmake/ctest

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, ctest

I manage a quite large open-source project with many unit-tests (~200 files) and passing all tests is quite time consuming for the continuous integration. We use cmake/ctest/Catch2 for the unit-test framework.

Is there a way to tell cmake/ctest to only build and run a random subset of the unit tests (e.g. just 30%) ?

When iterating with several commits on the code for a given feature, the probability that all tests where checked tends to one, but each individual commit would be way faster.

Obviously, this ratio would be set to 100% when preparing a PR or a release.

Comment: `Is there a way to tell cmake/ctest` yes, get all test, shuffle, get 30% of them, pass them to ctest. What have you tried?

Comment: Well.. I meant an automatic way to do that. Cherry-picking randomly some tests at each ctest call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ALTETRNATIVE**

Finally, I came up with a cmake solution just by creating a new `add_test()` function that activate a test upon a random test:

```
function(my_add_test test_file) #optional_avoid_add_test
  string(RANDOM LENGTH 2 ALPHABET "0123456789" _random)
  if (${_random} LESS ${THRESHOLD_RANDOM_TESTING})
    add_executable(${test_file} ${test_file}.cpp)
    add_test(${test_file} ${test_file})
  endif()
endfunction()
```

In my main `cmake` I have the global variable (that can be set at `cmake` CLI/GUI)

```
SET(THRESHOLD_RANDOM_TESTING "100" CACHE INTERNAL "~% of unit tests to build and run.")
```

Each time I regenerate the project, a new random selection is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell cmake/ctest

Yes. Get all test, shuffle, get 30% of them and pass them to back to ctest.

Looks like fun, in linux shell would be just:

```
ctest -N | sed -n 's/  Test #[0-9]\+: //p' | { tmp=$(cat); cnt=$(wc -l <<<"$tmp"); shuf -n "$((cnt * 30 / 100))" <<<"$tmp"; }
```

> I meant an automatic way to do that.

No, there is not.

Comment: nice workaround.. let me play around it. thx